# preg_replace() warning : Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I have this piece of code in order to replace the content inside a div, ">" and "<" are here to avoid the replace in other place of my page:

`$pageParticulier->post_content=preg_replace("#>"+$old_instance['title']+"<#", ">"+$new_instance['title']+"<",$pageParticulier->post_content);`

and i have this warning `preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

But the thing i don't understand is that i've already the delimiters for the pattern.

Comment: replace `+` by concatenation operatop - point - `"#>".$old_instance['title']."<#"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String concatenation in php is handled with a period `.` not a plus `+`:

```
$pageParticulier->post_content = preg_replace(
        "#>" . $old_instance['title'] . "<#", 
        ">" . $new_instance['title'] . "<",
        $pageParticulier->post_content
    );
```

Comment: Damn ! Merge js and php, nice...